# get all similar keys in JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, echo

let say, i have this JSON data i want to print all **key** by name "id", what should i do?

```
$json = {"response":[
  {
    "id": 37,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "38"
  },
  {
    "id": 38,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "40"
  }
]}
```

i tried this but this one is only giving me first array object sub key(which is id=37) i want all like (id=37, id=38)

```
$op =  $json->{'response'}[0]->{'id'};
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look like PHP to me, but a bad mixture between JSON and PHP. Can you clarify what your JSON actually looks like? Note that JSON is a string, not a structured data type! Also, what have you tried with it and what happened? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: One more hint: There is `jq` (CLI) and JsonDiscovery (browser) which are tools to display the structure within JSON and they could make this easier to understand.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you so much for your speedy reply:) ill try that for sure.

Comment: What else did you try to resolve the problem? With a single line of code, and a single scalar value, you cannot store multiple values

Comment: `$all_those_nice_little_ids = array_column($json->response, 'id');`

Answer (score 2):

If I assume your JSON is really JSON, and therefore a string, you could do this:

```
$json = '{"response":[
  {
    "id": 37,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "38"
  },
  {
    "id": 38,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "40"
  }
]}';

$data = json_decode($json);

$ids = array_column($data->response, 'id');

print_r($ids);
```

This would result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 37
    [1] => 38
)
```

See a [PHP Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/235a1f6f44b47edbfd58bf3164ef21122e28a3e7).

You can turn the JSON string into a usable PHP data with [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

The way to get the id's is by using [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column).

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your response

```
        $array = [];
        
        foreach ($json->{'response'} as $reponseItem){
            $array[$reponseItem['id']] = $reponseItem;
        }
```

Comment: yeah thats very great idea,looping thr array, just small change i did```$array = [];
        
  foreach ($json_response_all_voiceapps->{'response'} as $reponseItem){
      echo $reponseItem->{'app_id'};
  }```

Comment: You may also use array functions maybe there is a better way. If it is worked please mark it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode your json string into array 1st and then loop through data.

```
$json = ' {"response":[
  {
    "id": 37,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "38"
  },
  {
    "id": 38,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "40"
  }
]}';

$jsonArray =json_decode($json,true); //convert your json string to array.
$newJson  =  $jsonArray ['response']; 
foreach($newJson as $data)
{
  echo $data['id'];
}
```

OR You can directly loop through your `$jsonArray['response']`.

```
foreach($jsonArray['response'] as $data)
{
  echo $data['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '{"response":[
{
    "id": 37,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "38"
  },
  {
    "id": 38,
    "slug": "red",        
    "stock": true,
    "name": "Red",
    "default": 0,
    "sizes": "40"
  }
]}';

$data = json_decode($json);         // we decode the JSON

$num = count($data->response);      // we count how many response keys we have

$i=0;                               // define $1=0 to start our iteration
while ($i < $num) {                 // $i must be < than the counted array keys
    
    $op = $data->response[$i]->id;  // we tell the while loop to iterate over the array
    print $op."</br>";              // prints out 37 & 38
   
    $i++;                           // Standard incrementation

}
```